# Why does the jQuery tableFilter Plugin not work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tablefilter

I'm using the jQuery plugin called [tableFilter](http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/?page_id=16). It works beautifully in Firefox but in Internet Explorer, any table on the page gets hidden but there is nothing in the View Source that shows it hidden.

Has anyone using this plugin gotten it to work in Internet Explorer? I can't get the plugin developers [example](http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/jquery/tablefilter/tabletest.htm) to work in Internet Explorer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableFilter webpage appears to be down... here is a cached version of the site: ([link](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:2seXK6cpfJQJ:ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/%3Fp))

Have you considered trying the DataTables plugin instead?  www.datatables.net

Comment: Thanks! datatables.net was exactly what I needed instead. Does the same work of tableFilter and more.